# Can I perturb a sample drawn from a certain gaussian such that it becomes drawn from another gaussian?

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, density-function

Given **known** $v_1$ and $v_2$ such that $v_2 > v_1$, and an **unknown** $\mu$:

I have **a single sample** drawn from the distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, v_1)$.

Can I somehow perturb this sample in a sound way such that it becomes (as if) drawn from $\mathcal{N}(\mu, v_2)$?

e.g. if I sample from $\mathcal{N}(0, v_2-v_1)$ and add the result to the single sample I have. Would this make sense?

If not, any other/better suggestions?

Comment: This solution works when $v_2>v_1$.

Comment: Good point... Yes, that is indeed the use case. I will edit the question with the underlying assumption.

Comment: So the solution I suggest is mathematically/statistically sound?